# Loop through images with shared class in Jquery and apply Pixastic filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, pixastic

I am using pixastic (http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blend/) on a site I am implementing and need to use JQuery to loop though a collection of images that have a shared class and apply blend code to each image.

The sample code on the pixastic site doesn't make much sense to me (it looks like it is creating a new image) any help would be really appreciated.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {

var blendImg = new Image();
blendImg.onload = function() {
        Pixastic.process(img, "blend", 
            {
                amount : 1, 
                mode : "multiply", 
                image : blendImg
            }
        );
    }
    blendImg.src = "blendimage.jpg";
    }
img.src = "myimage.jpg";
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a shot in the dark here, but does this work?

```
$("img.yourClass").each(function() {
    Pixastic.process($(this).get(0), "blend", {
        amount: 1,
        mode: "multiply",
        image: [imageToBlendItWith]
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nick I will give it a go tonight